# I'm sending this http request but its passing % instead of @

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest-assured

This is the line where I'm sending a patch request

```
**request.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.body(requestParams.toString());
Response response = request.patch("/home/taha%40gmail.com");**
```

its failing because its passing %40 instead of @ between email. when I checked the logs (taha%40gmail.com)

How can I handle this in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Rest-Assured does URLencode out of the box, then you need to explicitly stop it.

```java
request.urlEncodingEnabled(false).patch("/home/taha%40gmail.com");
```

Comment: Thanks lucas.it was resolved by adding:                                                       
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given().urlEncodingEnabled(false);